# how to set PIKMG in delivery to 0?

Tags: sap-erp, bapi

In a return order flow I need to:

- post reverse goods issue ==> OK
- set `PIKMG` to 0 ==> ko
- modify `LFIMG` and post again the GI ==> OK

I can't find a way to do the second bullet, I tried with `BAPI_OUTB_DELIVERY_CHANGE` but without success.
Can someone post a good BAPI mapping for my requirement or suggest another BAPI?
Thank you very much.
Riky

Answer (score 0):

Use `WS_DELIVERY_UPDATE_2` BAPI for updating picking quantity.

FM call can look like this:

```
CALL FUNCTION 'WS_DELIVERY_UPDATE_2'
 EXPORTING
  vbkok_wa =       wa_vbkok " Header Data
  synchron =       'X'
  commit =         'X'
  delivery =       vbeln " delivery number
  update_picking = 'X'
  if_database_update_1 = '1'
 TABLES
  vbpok_tab =      it_vbpok[] " Item Data
  prot =           it_return. " Message Return Table

CLEAR: deliv_head,wa_vbkok.

READ TABLE it_return INTO wa_return WITH KEY msgty = 'E'.
IF sy-subrc <> 0.
  CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT'
   EXPORTING
    wait = 'X'.
ELSE.
* message handling
ENDIF.
```

Comment: thank you, i know the structure of the FM, the problem is how to populate item data